# Google App ScriptКак записать через get запрос информацию в определенную ячейку Google Таблицы - Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Кто может подсказать пример отправки данных в ячейки строк B и C

```
function doGet(e) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1P-erO-6HE6XzZVNu0VrnQJ0jW4tAOZX-lpKUF_bru6U");
    var n = sheet.getRange("Z1").getValue() + 2;
    var d = new Date();

    sheet.getRange("A" + n).setValue(d);
    sheet.getRange("B" + n).setValue(e.parameter.p1);
    sheet.getRange("C" + n).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
    sheet.getRange("Z1").setValue(n - 1);
}
```

Как сделать запись в строку, которая указывается через Get? То есть, если я захочу записать в строки G и H, что мне указать в запросе и как изменить код?

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант

```
...
// указываем диапазон с ячейки G1 по H10:
var range = sheet.getRange("G1:H10");
 // задаём ячейку, в которую будем писать, в данном случае это первая строка первая ячейка диапазона, т. е. ячейка G1
var cell = range.getCell(1,1);
// а вот так мы укажем на ячейку H5:
// var cell = range.getCell(2,5);
cell.setValue(XXX);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо